# Python, XML, bulk change alternative to iteration?

Tags: python, xml

In Python, is there a better way to change a bunch of elements in an XML doc than iterating through them?

Sample XML below. Relevant part is to subtract each Lap's Starttime from the timestamp on each Tracepoint. (Each Trackpoint has an absolute (Zulu-time) timestamp, and Trackpoints are part of a Lap that has its own absolute (Zulu-time) StartTime... desired outcome is that each Trackpoint has the *relative* time during the lap, not the time in Greenwich.)

Setting up the subtraction is straightforward with:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
dtLapStart = parse(eltLap.getAttribute('StartTime'))
```

Question is for each Track inside a Lap, is there a way to bulk perform this:

```
parse(timestamps[i].firstChild.data) - dtLapStart
```

for all the Time items, or do I need to iterate over the eltTrack.getElementsByTagName("Time") collection?

```
<Lap StartTime="2015-01-16T22:23:59.000Z">
        <Track>
          <Trackpoint>
            <Time>2015-01-16T22:24:00.000Z</Time>
            <HeartRateBpm>
              <Value>181</Value>
            </HeartRateBpm>
          </Trackpoint>
          <Trackpoint>
            <Time>2015-01-16T22:24:01.000Z</Time>
            <HeartRateBpm>
              <Value>181</Value>
            </HeartRateBpm>
            </Extensions>
          </Trackpoint>
<...>
```